# Why doesn't my Makita cordless circular saw start?

Tags: circular-saw

I just bought a brand new never used Makita cordless circular saw. I have attached the blade put on a brand new fully charged battery. It doesn't start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What model number is the saw and the battery? Can you press the trigger in at all?

Comment: Did you read through the manual? These things usually have one more safety interlock than you'd expect.

Comment: This really isn't enough detail for any of us to diagnose. Please edit to include pictures (if relevant), what you've done to fix the problem so far, whether or not any indicator LEDs illuminate, if the batteries also work in a different tool, whether different batteries work in this tool, etc.